# Google Charts not displaying value for haxis

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart

I am implementing Google Charts. The data is coming through correct, But I think due to size of bars the Haixs data is getting skipped in between.

[image]

This is an example of how data is passed to Charts.

In the graph, if you see the bars are more and the value on hAxis is less. It is skipping the value after every bar, but if I hover on the bar it does show the value.

Comment: "if (typeof(google) !== 'undefined')
 {
     var StageWiseData1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(Arr1);
  var StageWiseData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['SubStatus', 'Count'],
          ['Partner TAC 1 - CTN', 1],
          ['Partner JHB Systems', 6],
          ['Partner Tier 3 - CTN', 3],
          ['Carrier Telco Support', 4],
          ['Carrier Wholesale', 5],
    ['Carrier Wireless Support', 5],
    ['GSC Call Takers', 15],
    ['Cloud Security Installs', 1],
        ]);

Comment: Please include your current code in the question so that people can see what you have tried that is not working; this gives a basis to suggest improvements or corrections, especially if you have an almost-working solution

Comment: If the hAxis doesn't have enough room to display all the tick labels, it will start to skip some.  So increase the width of the chart, and maybe the chartArea.width.  Or you can enable more than one alternating rows of ticks, but your labels are long enough that that is not likely to work well.

Comment: You might be better off with a bar chart, by the way.  The domain axis is then oriented vertically, so your tick labels would be more readable horizontally.  You'll still have to leave enough space for them, by setting the chartArea.left, and give the chart enough height so ticks are not skipped.

Answer (score 0):

```
var options ={
      title: 'My SR By Sub Status',
              width: 600,
    height: 550,
      legend: { position: 'none' },

      chart: { subtitle: 'popularity by percentage' },
    /*  axes: {
        x: {
          0: { side: 'top', label: 'White to move'} // Top x-axis.
        }
      },*/
    };
 if (typeof(google) !== 'undefined') {
 /*var StageWiseData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['SubStatus', 'WithinSLA', 'Breached'],
      ['Unassigned', 3,1],
      ['Assigned', 2,1],
      ['In Progress', 2,5],
      ['Waiting for Client Info', 4,0],
      ['Waiting for Client Testing', 5,0],
      ['Waiting for Client Closure', 1,2],
       ['Waiting for Client Monitoring', 9,1],
       ['Waiting for Client Change', 1,0],
    ]);*/
    var StatusWiseData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(Arr);
 chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('mychart6'));
 chart.draw(StatusWiseData, options);
 }
```